# Cannot execute a Linux command from Java

Tags: java, linux, bash

I have a Linux command that I cannot execute from Java:

```
[ ! -d "/tmp/flow" ] && echo "The directory DOES NOT exist."
```

It works fine in command line but when I use the following code:

```
    String command = "[ ! -d \"/tmp/flow\" ] && echo \"The directory DOES NOT exist.\"";
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    Boolean successful = proc.waitFor()==0 && proc.exitValue()==0;
    System.out.println("successful:"+successful);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    String line = null;
    System.out.println("************** input");
    while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("************** error");
    while ((line = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

it says that

```
successful:false
************** input
************** error
[: missing ']'
```

Any idea? Is it possible that these IF bash operators cannot be called from Java...?

Thanks!

**************** UDATE ****************

```
vikhor@adnlt653-vm1:~> which '['
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[
[ is /bin/[
```

Comment: are you in same box where you are trying to execute mention command. if out side try to use jsch or any other libaray

Comment: I dont think there is an executable named "[" on Linux which does what you want. And do you really want to check for the presence of some directory using an external command?

Comment: Hi @spandey15, yes, I am on the same host.

Comment: Hi @GyroGearless, basically it is an IF operator, it tries to check if the folder exists. It works fine in command line. Usually it is used in bash scripts.

Comment: `Boolean successful = proc.waitFor()==0 && proc.exitValue()==0;` there's no need to check `exitValue()` if you've just checked the return of `waitFor()` as they will be the same. Print the actual int value instead of creating a Boolean object.

Comment: Hi, you are right, thanks! The status value is 2. As far as I know it only means that the command failed to execute, is that correct?

Comment: Try putting the command in a script file and execute that instead. You will probably need to chmod +x it first. Not very secure but it should work

Comment: What does the command `which '['` print?

Comment: Hi @DodgyCodeException , thanks, I will put the output to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[` command is a shell built-in. The `which` command shows that it's also an executable file. It is this executable file that gets executed when you pass the command line to `exec()`. So then the whole command line is passed to the `[` command. However, the `&&` operator is a shell operator. The `[` executable doesn't like it.

So you need to run the `bash` executable and pass the command as an argument:

```
String command = "bash -c '[ ! -d \"/tmp/flow\" ] && echo \"The directory DOES NOT exist.\"'";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, you must be right! However I cannot prove it as I get the following error when executing the command above:  *!: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
!: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file*

Comment: Your error message says "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `". That's a backquote character. Make sure you're using a straight quote.

Comment: Well, the strange thing is that there is no backquote in the command but only aposthrophe (I copied the command you provided). Anyway your answer is the correct one so I will accept it.

Comment: eventually the bash -c was the solution but your answer was the key, thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped. And thanks for pointing out what the correct command should have been. I've edited the answer for the benefit of any future readers.